# Putting a string through RSA encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I have the project in my coding security class. We are getting the P and Q values and the generating the D and E values for RSA encryption. All we have to do is encrypt a number and then decrypt it and I already have that working. I want to take string input and encrypt it.

Comment: What 5gon12eder said. However, I assume this is just a "toy" implementation of RSA, so it doesn't really matter if it's insecure and slow. How big is your n = PQ? It's easy enough to convert a string to a list of integers, and vice versa; the simplest way is to use Python's `ord` and `chr` functions, which operate on single character strings. But it would be better to operate on larger blocks of chars so that each block is converted to an integer u in the range  0 <= u < n. BTW, which Python version are you using?

Comment: Our P and Q values can be up to three digits so the N value can get pretty big. Okay I will look up how to use the ord and chr functions. I am using Python 3.4 right now.

Comment: `ord` and `chr` should be adequate for this. Your P & Q are relatively small, so your N can be easily factored by simple trial division almost instantly even with a relatively slow language like Python. P & Q need to be _much_ larger if you want secure RSA encryption.

Comment: Okay thanks I will give it a try. Yeah I know three digits are small, but all we are trying to do is get the general idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is not straight-forward and generally not desirable.

What one usually does is generating a random number, and use it as key in a *symmetric block cipher* such as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) that is capable of running in a [*mode of operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for encrypting arbitrarily long messages. Then encrypt the random number with RSA and send it along with the cipher-text obtained from the block cipher. If this sounds too complicated, you can instead construct a very simple (and not very secure) *stream cipher* that uses its key to seed a pseudo random number generator (PRNG) and then XORs the symbols of the plain text with the results of successive calls to the PRNG.

If encrypting strings directly with RSA is not a requirement for that class, I would stay away from it.  If you want to add something else to make your assignment more fancy, consider implementing [*padding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) instead.

If you absolutely have to do it, you have to define a bijective function that maps strings to integers. But since the message space is finite, this can only work for rather short strings.